# How to change default sort in custom subpanel - sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to put default sort by "Date Created" in custompanel.
can you please guide me, how can I make it "Date Created" as default sort?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `layout_defs` change the `sort_by` to the desired column :

```
<?php
   $layout_defs['ModuleName']['subpanel_setup']['Subpanelname'] = array(
        'order' => 50,
        'sort_order' => 'desc',
        'sort_by' => 'date_entered',
   );
?>
```

In this example, the default column used for sorting is `date_entered`

Comment: @SureshKumar no problem, i forgot to mention that after changes had been made, you need to repair and rebuild :P