# How to set a default sorting order for a subpanel in SugarCRM 7

Tags: sorting, sugarcrm

As in Sugarcrm 6.x we can set the default sorting order of a subpanel by changing the layout defs of the subpanel as explained here:

[How to change default sort in custom subpanel - sugarcrm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610322/how-to-change-default-sort-in-custom-subpanel-sugarcrm)

But how can i achieve the same sorting functionality in a standard subpanel visible in a sidecar enabled module in SugarCRM 7.6

Actually what i am trying to acheieve is setting a default sort by date_start DESC for a Meetings subpanel visible in Accounts module.

Any ideas how to implement this sorting functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need to copy the Meetings subpanel-definition to the custom directory;
modules/Meetings/clients/base/views/subpanel-list/subpanel-list.php

to

custom/modules/Meetings/clients/base/views/subpanel-list/subpanel-list.php

In your new file add the following after the "panels"-array

```
'orderBy' => array (
    'field' => 'date_modified',
    'direction' => 'desc',
),
```

Do a Quick repair and rebuild and meetings subpanels will now be sorted after date_modified!

Remember that if the user previously has sorted by any other field, they might not see your changes right away since their preferences are stored in their browser and are prioritized over your default sort order.