# How to change the default order of the sub panels in the opportunities module

Tags: sugarcrm

I have a need to change the default order of the sub panels in the opportunities module. I have been looking for a solution for a while and have not found a solution that works.
I am using SugarCRM CE 6.5.13
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is actually unclear. Are you asking for the order of a subpanel meaning how to place one subpanel above another. Or is your question concerning the order of the data inside a subpanel?

A fast response to both is:

in {MainModule}/metadata/subpaneldefs.php there should be the sort order declared for the subpanel like this:

```
$layout_defs[{MainModule}] = array(
    // list of what Subpanels to show in the DetailView 
    'subpanel_setup' => array(
        '{TheSubpanel}' => array(
            'order' => 1, // influences the place of the subpanel relative to the other subpanels
            'module' => '{TheSubpanel}',
            'subpanel_name' => 'default', // attention please check the subpanel module to make sure there is not another setting overriding this setting
            'sort_order' => 'desc',
            'sort_by' => 'date_entered',
 ...
```

check also the file defined above that contains the subpanels fields. In this case it can be found in {TheSubpanel}/metadata/subpanels/default.php

```
$module_name = '{TheSubpanel}';
$subpanel_layout = array(
    'top_buttons' => array(
    'where' => '',
    'sort_order' => 'desc',
    'sort_by' => 'date_entered',
```

Please consider that after a change you need to run 'rebuild & repair' and if you manually clicked on a sort field then you should clear your cookie cache and log in again too.

There are other questions on stack overflow concering this like [how-to-change-default-sort-in-custom-subpanel-sugarcrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610322/how-to-change-default-sort-in-custom-subpanel-sugarcrm)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response to this question.   I am attempting to change the order in which the sub panels are displayed within the modules detail view. Example in Opportunities a record is selected and you have Opportunity Summary at the top then {some-panel-1} below that, then below that {some-panel-2}, and so on.  RE:There are other questions on stack overflow concering this like how-to-change-default-sort-in-custom-subpanel-sugarcrm.      I had looked and was unsure as to how I could choose the order rather then just a desc. Thank you for providing such a clear answer.

Comment: So the 'order' parameter would be your thing. Thank you too for your response, please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: How do I change the order the panels that are not listed within subpaneldefs.php file? Is there another place to find the remaining panels?

Comment: One other thought. As I make these changes will they become each users new subpanel layout, or will their personal preferences take precedence? If personal preferences does take precedence how can I ensure my code takes precedence?

Comment: please give a concrete example of your modules subpanels. the user prefs are just temporary afaik, so delete cookies and cache. And by the way  thats another question :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want code level customization then you can just drag and drop the sequence of subpanels on detail view of record. The sequence of subpanel will be saved.

Comment: Thanks,  I am aware of the drag and drop method. I should have been more clear. I need a code level change that will become the new default order for all users.